Unreal Engine macOS cannot create / build C++ projects on external volume
I use Unreal Engine 5.4.3 on macOS and I'm having trouble with building C++ projects while locating them on an external volume. The UnrealBuildTool output is the following:
Setting up bundled DotNet SDK
/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_5.4/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Mac/../../../Binaries/ThirdParty/DotNet/6.0.302/mac-arm64
Running dotnet Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.dll -projectfiles -project=/Volumes/xxx/Projects/Unreal/MyProject/MyProject.uproject -game -rocket -progress
Log file: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Epic/UnrealBuildTool/Log_GPF.txt

Generating XCode project files:y
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
Errors generated while parsing '/Volumes/xxx/Projects/Unreal/MyProject/Source/MyProject/._MyProject.Build.cs'
/Volumes/xxx/Projects/Unreal/MyProject/Source/MyProject/._MyProject.Build.cs(1,1): error CS1056: Unexpected character '/Volumes/xxx/Projects/Unreal/MyProject/Source/MyProject/._MyProject.Build.cs(1,46): error CS1056: Unexpected character '�'
/Volumes/xxx/Projects/Unreal/MyProject/Source/MyProject/._MyProject.Build.cs(1,47): error CS1056: Unexpected character '/Volumes/xxx/Projects/Unreal/MyProject/Source/MyProject/._MyProject.Build.cs(1,158): error CS1056: Unexpected character '�'
/Volumes/xxx/Projects/Unreal/MyProject/Source/MyProject/._MyProject.Build.cs(1,161): error CS1056: Unexpected character '�'
/Volumes/xxx/Projects/Unreal/MyProject/Source/MyProject/._MyProject.Build.cs(1,162): error CS1056: Unexpected character '�'

This does not happen when I build a Blueprint project or if I locate the project for example in my Documents folder. Currently I'm using XCode, but the problem still occurs with other IDEs such as VSCode or CLion.
The error messages look like there are some issues with character encoding, but I didn't find any configurations for this. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

I actually figured it out myself. The problem was that the external volume had an exFAT filesystem type. After changing it to APFS, it all worked out fine.
I suppose macOS has some problems with exFAT and character encoding or something, but this is only my suggestion. Eventually, someone else will know where the problem is.
